# Unable to Perform NULL value analysis in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I want to perform NULL values analysis here.
Here i have mentioned first 2 rows of the dataset

```
Shop_name         Bikes_avaiable             Shop_location       Average_price_of_bikes   Rating_of_shop

NYC Velo          Ninja,hbx                      Salida                   5685$               4.2               
Bike Gallery      dtr,mtg,Harley Davidson        Portland                 6022$               4.8
```

Except shop_name, every columns has some NULL values.

Earlier i had used mean based imputation and frequency based imputation to replace NULL values.

But, i have been told to follow the model based imputation technique to replace all
the NULL value.

Can anyone suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess model based imputation technique refers to using statistical models to predict the missing values. For example, you can use `K-Nearest Neighbours` model to predict missing values. Train the KNN model using data points on the rows where no missing value exists and predict the missing values based on the rows where there are missing values. You would have to apply one-hot encoding for categorical values.